# How to use same path in loadChildren for Nativescript and Angular?

Tags: angular, routes, nativescript

I have a project using Angular and Nativescript, and we'd like to use the same routes.

Here's how my routes look like:

```
    {
        path: '',
        component: BaseComponent
    },
    {
        path: 'details',
        //loadChildren: '~/app/Routes/base/details/details.module#DetailsModule',
        loadChildren: './details/details.module#DetailsModule',
    }
```

The commented one works on Nativescript, but not on Angular. The other one works on Angular but not on Nativescript.

How can I use the same path to lazy load my module in Nativescript AND Angular, without having 2 files?

Thanks in advance!
Have a great day :)

Comment: Try to set it up in different `environment` files and use it as a variable (or just as a path prefix). This may work as it should not have problems with AoT

Comment: @smnbbrv Yeah That could work for this specific case, but I organized my routes in a lot of directory. So, my path in environment for Angular will be "." only, but in Nativescript, it will be "./app/Routes/base/", "./app/Routes/admin/", etc.

Comment: I think you could tweak your `tsconfig.json` to support similar path for both environment.

Comment: Post the solution as an answer and accept it yourself. Don't add it to the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case someone's having this problem, you can do this:

```
{
    path: '',
    component: BaseComponent
},
{
    path: 'details',
    loadChildren: () => DetailsModule,
}
```

The import is a relative path and work wit both of the platform

Comment: Wouldn't the details module have to be imported in this routing module for it to work? If so, wouldn't that module then have to eagerly load?